# Nginx force port 8080 to use SSL and rewrite or redirect http to https

Tags: nginx, proxy, rewrite

Hi I am forcing nginx to use SSL for port `8080`, here is my conf:

```
server {
        listen        8080 ssl;
        server_name   example.com;
        access_log   /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

        include /etc/nginx/ssl.conf;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://192.168.1.20;
        }

    }
```

the `https://example.com:8080` works fine but when use `http://example.com:8080` the nginx has the error message shown:

```
The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
```

now my question is how to get `http://example.com:8080` auto redirect or rewrite to `https://example.com:8080` by editing my nginx conf file?

Comment: I don't think so. I tried "listen 80 http ssl" but http isn't a valid directive. I think it's one protocol per port, you'll have to find another way to do this.

Comment: duplicate question, answer is here
http://serverfault.com/a/750340/99453